# How to make a code for proper threading usage

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading, port-scanning

This is what I am doing right now.

```
def formate(newurl1, schemess):

    newurl = newurl1.replace('http://', '')
    portss = 21, 22, 80, 8080, 443, 8443, 3306, 445 
    th1 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess, 21,))
    th2 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args=( newurl, schemess, 22,))
    th3 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess,80,))
    th4 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args=(newurl, schemess,8080,))
    th5 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess,443,))
    th6 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess,8443,))
    th7 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess,3306,))
    th8 = threading.Thread(target=connCheck,  args= (newurl, schemess,445,))

    print "\n Host:- ", newurl1, "\n"
    print "\t[+] List of open ports:-"

    th1.start()
    th2.start()
    th3.start()
    th4.start()
    th5.start()
    th6.start()
    th7.start()
    th8.start()
    th8.join()

    for x in urls_returning200:

        formate(x, '')
```

NOTE:-  **connCheck** is my another function for creating sockets. so, that does not need to define here.

Now all the work is going good, what I want to know that, Is there any alternative for that? Means, this code is working perfectly for me what its quite lengthy which is really not good. So Is there anyone who can suggest me something?

**What I had tried.**

```
threadingss = []

def formate(newurl1, schemess):
    portss =  21, 22, 80, 8080, 443, 8443, 3306, 445
    for x in portss:

        threadin = threading.Thread(target=connCheck, args(newurl, schemess, x))
        threadingss.append(threadin)

for x in threadingss:
    x.start()

for x in threadingss:
    x.join()

for x in urls_returning200:

    formate(x, '')
```

But that cause error so that also doesn't work for me?

So please suggest me something.

Comment: @Andersson would like to suggest me something?

Comment: @argo would like to suggest me something?

Comment: What error specifically do you get? Can you copy/paste the traceback into the question?

Comment: The thread can be started once.