# How to store multiple values in keys in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Maybe my question title is different from the question content.

```
statuscode = []
statuscode.append(200) 

for x in find_from_sublister(hostname):
    x2 = x.strip()
    url = "http://"+ x2
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
        req1 = str(req.status_code) + " " + str(url) + '\n'
        req2 = str(req.status_code)
        req3 = str(url)
        dict = {req2 : req3}

        print " \n " + str(req1)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print "Can't make the request to this Subdomain " + str(url) + '\n'

for keys, values in dict.iteritems():
    print "finding the url's whose status code is 200"

    if keys == statuscode[0]:
        print values
    else:
        print "po"
```

I am using the code to do some following stuffs.

1. It will find the subdomains from the Sub-lister (Locally)
2. Then it will go to find the status code of each subdomain which was find by the sublister, with the help of ***for loop***. `for x in find_from_sublister(hostname):`

**Note: find_from_sublister(hostname) is a function for finding the subdomain from the sublister.**

3. Then print the status code with the URL. Here `print " \n " + str(req1)`

[All goes well, but the problem starts here ]

Now what I want is to **seperate the URLs which have 200 status code.**

so I heard then it can happen by using the dictionary in python. So, I try to use the dictionary. As you can see `dict = {req2 : req3}`

Now I also make a list of index which have value `200`

Then I compare the keys to list of index. here `keys == statuscode[0]`

and if they match then it should print all the URL's which have 200 status code.

But the result I am getting is below,

```
finding the url's whose status code is 200 
po
```

You see the value `po` its else statment value,

```
else:
   print "po"
```

**Now the problem is Why I am getting this else value why not the URL's which have status code 200?**

Hope I explained you clearly. And waiting for someone who talk to me on this.

Thanks

Note: I am Using Python 2.7 ver.

Comment: the code is hard to read but maybe it's because you're comparing `int` and `str`? 

`req2 = str(req.status_code)`  means `req2 = "200"` but `statuscode[0] = 200` and doing `200 == "200"` will output `False`

Comment: I think your dict has one (key, value) because you do assignment in each iteration rather than updating the dict with new values. Am i missing something?

Comment: You have to create a dictionary *outside* of the loop and *update* it in the loop. As it is now, you are throwing away every dictionary but the last one!

Comment: @wilfo Nice catch man, Its actually print the URL, but problem still is, Suppose I have two urls which have same 200 status code, So, I can only  print the second URL's not the first one. That's the problem

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Would you like to say something on my above comment.

Comment: @galmeriol Can you please give me the idea How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you don't even need the dictionary.

I've tried to clean up the code as much as possible, including more descriptive variable names (also, it's a bad idea to override builtin names like `dict`).

```
urls_returning_200 = []

for url in find_from_sublister(hostname):
    url = "http://" + url.strip()
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            urls_returning_200.append(url)
        print " \n {} {}\n".format(response.status_code, url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print "Can't make the request to this Subdomain {}\n".format(url)

print "finding the url's whose status code is 200"
print urls_returning_200
```

Comment: I want to print the URL which has the status code 200.

Comment: I've made an edit to simplify my answer, I think this should be clearer than my initial answer.

Comment: Yeah! Perfect, Could you explain this? I mean what I was trying and How you understood the weakness?

Comment: The two main issues were the difference between `int` and `str` (that is, `200 != '200'`: the first is a number and the second is text), and the difference between assignment and updating: you created a whole new dictionary with one key and one value in every iteration of the loop, while you really want to keep that information. Apart from that, the solution you were going for was far more complicated than it needed to be. That's something you'll get a feel for as you keep practising.

Comment: Yes!! Will do. ;)

Comment: Hi, @Robin I have a problem. Actually, your code was awesome, but now I need to create the **Dictionary** not **list of index**. I did somethings but Unable to achieve it. Can you please make the code of making the dictionary instead of a list of index. Looking for you reply.

Comment: I would like to help, but it is not clear to me what you actually need.

Comment: Hi robin, would you like to say  something on that quest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48904041/how-to-make-a-code-for-proper-threading-usage